# Having Powershell Autofill command line prompt

Tags: powershell

There is an old command line tool my company uses to deploy log files to various servers.... whoever wrote it made it very very repetitive.

There is a lot of prompting that happens and I want to automate this process. We have a long term goal of replacing this .exe file down the line but for now automation works for the short term..

Example

```
./logdeploy.exe
Enter the destination folder:
```

I would like the powershell script to just automatically enter the folder, since its literally the same folder. because this exe is going to ask for it at least 20 times throughout this process, so copy paste just gets anyoing.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Does `logdeploy.exe` have an unattended flag? Is it able to take the destination folder as argument?

Comment: There are several things it asks for... the destination folder, then it will ask for the password to that folder, then it will do the deploy, then it will ask for the next folder, then the password to that folder, then deploy etc, repeat about 20 times..

Comment: If it asks a fixed number of times, you could simply pipe input like this: `@('c:\foo') * 20 | ./logdeploy.exe` -- This would automate 20 prompts for input.

Comment: I dont want to run the exe 20 times, it already prompts a fix number of times.

Comment: @zett42 Yeah, this would be my suggestion too. You can also safely pass a huge number of inputs if the process automatically exits at some point after a variable number of inputs: `,'C:\destination\path' * 1MB |./logdeploy.exe`

Comment: @Bnd10706 it's not going to run `./logdeploy.exe` 20 times, it's going to run it once, but feed 20 consecutive input strings to the resulting process' stdin

Comment: This would work even if the password? it needs to do the destination folder, then the password to the folder. then it will repeat.

Comment: @Bnd10706 Why are you asking us? You're the only person with access to the software :) `@('C:\path', 'password') * 20 | ./logdeploy.exe`

Answer (score 2):

If there really is no way around simulating interactive user input in order to automate your external program, a solution is possible under the following **assumption**:

- Your **external program reads interactive responses from *stdin*** (the standard input stream).

  - While doing so is typical, it's conceivable that a given program's *security-sensitive* prompts such as for passwords deliberately accept input from the *terminal* only, as so to expressly prevent *automating* responses.
- If the first assumption holds, the **specific method that must be used** to send the response strings via stdin **depends on *whether the external program clears the keyboard buffer before each prompt***.

  - (a) If it does *not*, you can simply send all strings in a single operation.
  - (b) If it *does*, you need to *insert delays* between sending the individual strings, so as to ensure that input is only sent when the external program is actively prompting for input.

    - This approach is inherently *brittle*, because in the absence of being able to *detect* when the external program is read to read a prompt response, you have to *guess* how much time needs to elapse between sending responses - and that time may vary based on many runtime conditions.
    - It's best to use *longer* delays for better reliability, which, however, results in increased runtime overall.

**Implementation of (a)**:

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) and [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) suggest, use the following to send strings `C:\foo` and `somepass` 20 times to your external program's stdin stream:

```sh
('C:\foo', 'somepass') * 20 | ./logdeploy.exe
```

Again, this assumes that `./logdeploy.exe` *buffers* keyboard input it receives *before* it puts up the next prompt.

**Implementation of (b)**:

Note: The following **works in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* only**, because only there is command output being sent to an external program properly *streamed* (sent line by line, as it becomes available); unfortunately, *Windows PowerShell* collects all output *first*.

```sh
# PowerShell 7+ only
# Adjust the Start-Sleep intervals as needed.
1..20 | ForEach-Object { 
  Start-Sleep 1
  'C:\foo'
  Start-Sleep 2
  'somepass' 
} | ./logdeploy.exe
```