# Fill multiple answers in Powershell command prompt with script

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, command-prompt

I am trying to automate filling the answers of a prompt with a Powershell script. The prompt questions looks like this :

[image: Powershell user prompt]

The questions are generated one after the other by the .cmd file (meaning that the input does not go back to the Powershell input). I found many answers to fill one question at time or multiple Y/N questions, but not something like this yet.

Comment: It depends on what program(s) is/are generating the prompts. Not enough information in your question to really answer.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart it's the config.cmd file (used to configure a self hosted DevOps agent)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart and I am looking for the equivalent of this answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512368) in Powershell

Comment: Again: This depends on the program (by which I mean, the actual Windows _executable file_) is reading the input from the prompt. Depending on how the prompt is read from the user, you may or may not be able to automate it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply provide the responses to the anticipated prompts as an array of (single-line) strings:

```bash
'answer to prompt 1',
# ...
'answer to prompt N' |
  config.cmd
```

Note:

- This works only:

  - with *external programs* - such as `.cmd` (batch) files interpreted by `cmd.exe` - and not with PowerShell commands that use [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) to prompt for input, and assumes that that these programs read responses *from stdin*.
  - if there is a fixed set of known prompts - conditional variations cannot be handled this way.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72191533/45375) for more information on the constraints of this approach.