# How to execute commands using powershell after doing remote login using winrs

Tags: powershell, winrm, winrs

I am new to PowerShell scripting. So please pardon me if I am asking a silly question.
I have a task to connect to the command prompt of a remote desktop and run a series of commands on the command line.

I am using winrm to access the remote desktop machine. I have written the following code in a test.ps1 file:

```
powershell.exe -c "winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts=remoteHostServer}'"
powershell.exe -c "winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx cmd.exe"
powershell.exe -c "C:\test\"
powershell.exe -c "java test.java"
```

When I am executing the above code, I am reaching the following line:

```
C:\Users\admin>
```

But then it is not changing the directory to the path "C:\test" and execute the java file. Can anyone say what else should I do to execute the java files present in the path "C:\test" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Instead of using [`winrs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/winrs) calls via `powershell.exe` to execute remote commands, consider using *PowerShell*'s [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote), which is equally [WinRM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management)-based.

---

- You don't need to make your `winrm` and `winrs` calls via `powershell.exe`.
- To execute a command *remotely*, you must submit it as part of the `winrs` command line.
- Separate `powershell.exe` calls create independent sessions, so you cannot use one call to create state for another; use a *single* call with *multiple commands*.

Therefore:

```bash
winrm set winrm/config/client "@{TrustedHosts=remoteHostServer}"
winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -c "Set-Location C:\test; java test.java"
```

Note that you do not need PowerShell to execute your specific remote command either.
Here's the version without PowerShell, using the `-d` option to set the remote working directory:

```bash
winrm set winrm/config/client "@{TrustedHosts=remoteHostServer}"
winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx -dC:\test java test.java
```

Note that the remote `cmd.exe` session that `winrs` implicitly creates automatically ends when a given command finishes executing (the `powershell ...` call in this case).
That is, the remote session ends and returns control to the caller once the remote command terminates.

An *interactive* remote session can only be entered if you specify a *shell executable* as the command to execute, such as `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` *without arguments* (or with `/K` / `-NoExit`).
However, note that the commands you submit remotely will be *echoed* before their output prints; while there is a `-noecho` option to suppress that, it unfortunately also hides *commands as they're being typed*.

---

**Sending *many* commands to execute remotely via `winrs.exe` and PowerShell:**

The above shows that you can simply pass multiple commands, separated with `;`, inside the `"..."` string passed to the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI.
Given that the command-line length limit is close to 32,767 characters, this makes it possible to send many commands.
However, the single-line requirement and the need to escape embedded `"` chars. make this approach awkward.

The alternatives are:

- (Untested) **Place the commands in a `*.ps1` script file on a file share** that is accessible from the remote machine and invoke it from there, using `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ...`; doing so also requires passing the `/allowdelegate` option to `winrs`; e.g.:

  ```bash
  winrs /r:remoteHostServer /allowdelegate /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "\\Server1\share1\script.ps1"
  ```

  - **Note**: If the script to execute is on the remote machine's *local drive*, simply *use the local path* - no need for a file share or `/allowdelegate`
  - Caveat: If the [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) on the remote machine is GPO-controlled, `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` will have no effect.
- ***Pipe* the contents of a script file to `powershell -c -`**, i.e. make the remote PowerShell instance read the commands to execute *from stdin*:

  ```bash
  type script.ps1 | winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -c -
  ```

  - **Note**: Since you're sending *code* via stdin in this case, you cannot also send *data* that way; if you need the latter (e.g. to automate `Read-Host` responses), you'll have to use the script-file-based approach or the approach where you pass the code directly to
    `-c`
  - **Caveat**: Using `-Command -` (`-c -`) has quirks, notably:

    - **Make sure that `script.ps1` has *two* newlines at the end of the file** - otherwise, a multi-line statement (anywhere in the script) that isn't followed by an empty line won't get processed, along with any subsequent statements.
    - Each statement received via stdin executes in a *separate pipeline* (this slows down execution and can affect for-display output formatting)
    - See [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223) for details.

Comment: Thanks mklement0, but I need to run plenty of commands after logging into the remote machine. So the following line of code will continue to grow like anything: 

winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -c "Set-Location C:\test; java test.java"


So can you please advise how can we include all the commands? Can't we send them in different lines?

Comment: Hi mklement0, 

Thanks for the further clarifications. Now consider the following command: 
winrs /r:remoteHostServer /allowdelegate /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "\\Server1\share1\script.ps1"

Here can I place the file script.ps1 in any location (say C:\script.ps1) of the remote machine? And in the script.ps1 I just need to write just the list of all the commands or should I write them in specific syntax like we do in a typical powershell script? Please clarify.

Comment: @RDX, If the script to execute is on the remote machine's _local drive_, simply *use the local path* - no need for a file share or `/allowdelegate`. You only need the latter if you don't want to copy the script to the remote machine first. Either way, your `*.ps1` script must be a regular PowerShell script (which in the simplest case is a list of commands, each on its own line).

Comment: @ mklement0, Thanks for those info. Now I am able to execute multiple lines of code. But still one place I am getting stuck. Some of the commands asks users to give the inputs for the prompts. For ex consider the following prompt - + Enter user: 
When I send Joe, it says "The term 'Joe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,..." Can you please say how can we send the inputs for the prompt? Remember the user input should be via automation, not manual.

Comment: @RDX: If you have control over the script, I suggest modifying it to accept _arguments_
instead of using `Read-Host` calls. If that is not an option, you can pipe
the automated responses the `Read-Host` responses to the `winrs` call, e.g.:
From PowerShell ``'jdoe' | winrs -r:localhost powershell -c '$user = Read-Host; \"You entered: $user\"'``
From `cmd.exe`: ``echo jdoe | winrs -r:localhost powershell -c "$user = Read-Host; \"You entered: $user\""``

Comment: Suppose I run this : `type script.ps1 | winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -c -` where script.ps1 has the command which will give a prompt for username. Then how can I accept the prompt because I think `'jdoe' | winrs -r:localhost powershell -c '$user = Read-Host; \"You entered: $user\"'` which you gave can be run separately. In my case I need to run just script.ps1 and that should automatically handle the prompt. Please advise what to do here.

Comment: Suppose I am executing this command `winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -c "Set-Location C:\test; java test.java"
`  and the file test.java asks for a prompt "Enter name:". So in this case how can I pass the value? `winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -c "Set-Location C:\test; java test.java; echo 'Joe'` - will this command work? For me it is not entering the value 'Joe' in the prompt. How should I pass it?

Comment: @RDX, as the examples in my previous comment shows, you must provide the responses _via stdin_, i.e. via a _pipeline_. If you need to provide _multiple_ responses, provide them as separate strings; e.g., from PowerShell: `'response1', 'response2' | winrs ...` For more information, including about limitations, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72191533/45375).

Comment: Ok. I tried this - `'Joe' | winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -c "Set-Location C:\test; java test.java;`$user1 = Read-Host;"` . For this I am getting the following error: `Enter the prefix for users:java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Enter the Name:`

See the prompt is coming after the exception but the user input is not getting accepted also... So how can I send that?

Comment: @RDX, Id don't know what your Java program does, but if it reads from stdin, it should see the `Joe` string. Once that is consumed, the `Read-Host` call would then receive _no_ input. Given that this answer addresses your question as asked and that you're now asking about a follow-up problem, I suggest creating a new question post focused on just your follow-up problem, ideally using a [mcve].

Comment: Ok thanks a lot @mklement0. I will create a new question...