# Passing a parameter to .exe, using powershell

Tags: powershell, input, command-line, exe

there is a need to run a console application .exe, which does array sorting, through powershell 50 times to find out the average running time of the application. I want the input to the application to be automatic. But it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Code powershell:

```
$asm_average=0
$cycles = 50
FOR ($i = 1; $i -lt $cycles; $i++)
{

echo "ASM CODE:"
$x = (get-date).ToString('yymmddhhmmssfff')
$o = Get-Random -InputObject (1..100) -Count 30
$c = ($o -join ' ').ToString()

D:\lr\projects\helloworld\pp2.exe "$c" $wshell.SendKeys('~') -Wait ??
$y = (get-date).ToString('yymmddhhmmssfff')

$y = $y - $x
echo "TIME:", $y
echo ""
$asm_average = $asm_average + $y

}
$asm_average = $asm_average / $cycles
echo "ASM AVERAGE TIME:", $asm_average
```

how work's exe:
Input array:
5 8 9 3 4 2 0 66
Sorted array: 0 2 3 4 5 8 9 66

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mashiro. Would you say mor about "it doesn't work?" Are there error messages? In what way(s) does it not work?

Comment: The arguments have to be treated as a single entity.  The easiest way is to create a variable for the arguments : $arguments = "$c $wshell.SendKeys('~') -Wait ??".  Then your command line would be : D:\lr\projects\helloworld\pp2.exe $arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **you're trying to automate a response to an *interactive prompt* presented by an external program**:

- The ***best* approach** is to investigate whether there is a way to ***avoid* such prompts**, **using a *parameter* supported by the target program, *if possible*** (such as `-y` to automatically confirm *yes/no* prompts, or a parameter that accepts an argument that would otherwise be prompted for).
- The ***next best* approach** is to try to **provide automated responses *via stdin***, which in PowerShell means *piping them* to the target program; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Equivalent to pressing ENTER when pp2.exe presents an interactive prompt.
  '' | D:\lr\projects\helloworld\pp2.exe "$c"
  ```

  - This assumes that the target program reads user input *from stdin* (the standard input stream), which solicits interactive user input from the terminal (console) *unless redirected*.
  - However, programs may choose to read from the terminal (console) *explicitly*, independently of stdin.
- The ***least desirable* approach** is to ***simulate interactive user input* by *sending keystrokes***, which is *inherently brittle*:

  ```bash
  # Simulate sending an ENTER keypress to the target program.
  (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys('~')
  D:\lr\projects\helloworld\pp2.exe "$c"
  ```

  - The above assumes that the target program accepts *buffered* keyboard input; if not, more work is needed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72191533/45375).